# Recall API after Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com

Tags: node.js, api, express, video, youtube

I'm building web application with MEAN, the application should check YouTube videos availability for given urls

The application fetch videos ids from database, for each id it call YouTube API to check if video exist then update database with result

im getting this error randomly with some IDs

> { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com
>   www.googleapis.com:443]   code: 'ENOTFOUND',   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
>   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',   hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',   host:
>   'www.googleapis.com',   port: 443 }

I searched, and I figured out it occur due error in connection.

However, I can't get it to recall YouTube API again if failed

here is my code

Call YouTube API

```
function (youtubeId,id){

  var searchParams = {
    part:             'id',
    id:                youtubeId
  }

  youtube.videos.list(searchParams, function(err, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return
    }
    MongoClient.connect(config.databaseUrl, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err)
      } else {
        if (body.items.length) {
          db.collection(config.collectionName).update({_id:id},{$currentDate:{"lastChecked": true}, $set: {"lastResponse":1}},function (err, numUpdated) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            } else if (numUpdated) {
              console.log(youtubeId+ ' is available >> ID '+ id)
            } else {
              console.log('No document found with defined "find" criteria!')
            }
            //Close connection
            db.close()
          })
        }
          else {
            db.collection(config.collectionName).update({_id:id},{$currentDate:{"lastChecked": true}, $set: {"lastResponse":0}},function (err, numUpdated) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err)
              } else if (numUpdated) {
                console.log(youtubeId+ ' is unavailable >> ID '+ id)
              } else {
                console.log('No document found with defined "find" criteria!')
              }
              //Close connection
              db.close()
            })
          }
      }
      })
    })

  }
```

Get Videos IDs

```
app.get('/run', function (req, res) {
  MongoClient.connect(config.databaseUrl, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err)
    } else {
      console.log('Connection established to', config.databaseUrl)
      var cursor = db.collection(config.collectionName).find()
      cursor.sort({"priority": 1, 'lastChecked': 1})
      cursor.skip(0)
      cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          if(doc !== null){
            //check which video to check
            if (checkPriority(doc.lastChecked,doc.priority)) {
              youtubeChecker(doc.youtubeID,doc._id)
            }
            else {
              console.log("No Videos to check");
            }
          }
        }
      })
    } 
  }) 

})
```